# Apache - Only redirect root url to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I got a snippet in my htaccess like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain\.de$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ de/deutschland/example [L]
```

I'm trying to redirect my-domain.de to my-domain/de/deutschland/example - but only the root url, all other urls/subfolders have to stay the same.
Unfortunately I'm getting an endless redirect, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.de$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /de/deutschland/example [R=301,L]
```

Remember that all redirects then get re-processed by htaccess so if you have any other rules that `/de/deutscheland/example` might match then you could theoretically end up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Jon works perfectly for me. The only modification was that I had to put it in my virtual host file rather than the .htaccess because the rewrite engine wasn't allowed in my htaccess file for some reason and produced an error in Apache.

My full config looks like this now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/requests.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /deutschland/example [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I changed the last http to https which I imagine might prevent causing a redirect from http->https, but I'm a noob so I don't know for sure. All I know is that this configuration is working exactly like I want it to, and both http and https seem to work.